# PHP change code for youtube video in curly brackets

Tags: php, regex, joomla, youtube

I have a Joomla website that has this code to load a plugin and include a video from Youtube.

```
{youtube width="640" height="420"}kHRf01Gjosk{/youtube}
```

The thing is that this code was for Joomla 1.5, now I have upgraded my website to Joomla 2.5 and that plugin stopped working and the creator won't upgrate it to 2.5, so I figured if I install another plugin that uses a very similar code, I could make it work with regex.

The new plugin supports this kind of code:

```
{youtube}kHRf01Gjosk|640|420{/youtube}, or {youtube}kHRf01Gjosk{/youtube}
```

I'm a complete idiot in a complex regex, so if anyone could help I would really appreciate it!

Thanks :)

Comment: Why are you talking of regex ? For example this works {youtube}kHRf01Gjosk|640|420|1{/youtube} with 1 for autoplay, and 0 if not

Comment: Because I have hundreds of k2 articles with the Joomla 1.5 code: {youtube width="640" height="420"}kHRf01Gjosk{/youtube} that doesn't work in 2.5, as it should be: {youtube}kHRf01Gjosk|640|420{/youtube}

Comment: I am not a regex specialist but it should look like ^\{youtube\}[A-Za-z0-9]*\{\/youtube\}

Comment: OK nevermind I found another way... Thanks anyway :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind after making some changes I figured it out... Thanks for all the help Newben!

Comment: This isn't really an answer. Perhaps you could detail the alternative way in which you implemented it?